# Passing twig data to vue js in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, vue.js

I am using a component named "`vue-cookie-law` in my symfony application so I call it like that in my base (default twig template):

```
<div id="CookieLaw" data-locale="{{ app.request.locale }}"></div>
```

and then in my vue template I have this:

```
<template>
     <div id="CookieLaw">
         <cookie-law theme="base" transitionName="slideFromBottom">
            <div slot="message">{{ locale }}En poursuivant votre navigation sur notre site vous acceptez l'utilisation de cookies, pour vous proposer des contenus personnalisés en fonction de vos centres d'intérêt et mesurer la fréquentation de nos services, pour en savoir plus et paramétrer les cookies, cliquez ici </div>
        </cookie-law>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import CookieLaw from 'vue-cookie-law'
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
               locale: ""
            }
        },
        components: { CookieLaw },
        beforeMount: () => {
            this.locale = this.$el.attributes['data-locale'].value;
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
    .Cookie {
    background: white;
   padding: 2rem;
}
</style>
```

And my js part :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import CookieLaw from './components/CookieLaw';

new Vue({
    el: '#CookieLaw',
    render: h => h(CookieLaw)
});
```

So I try to pass the `locale` variable of my app but I have an error like that :

[Vue warn]: Error in beforeMount hook: "TypeError: _this.$el is undefined

So it seems I can't access my data attributes like that. Any idea on what I'm doing the wrong way here ? could it be a conflict between twig and vue ?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram - I would bet it's too early to use `$el` :P

Comment: it does the same on "mounted"

Comment: Can you just show the result of `mounted () { console.log(this.$el) }`

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: That's weird. Move it to `updated` and see what happens. Anyway it would be easier if you set the data attribute to binded property so you can just get it later on in props :P

Comment: nothing happens with updated

Comment: I try to figure out what exactly is happening with your code but I'm very confused. Could you edit your answer and add a comment from which file is every part of code you posted? Do you mean <div is="CookieLaw" instead of <div id="CookieLaw"> in your first code block? In which file does the second code block exist?

Comment: i really meant id="CookieLaw" becasue its the target element of my vue component. i've added my js part to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the value of `this.$el`? I suspect that it targets `<div id="CookieLaw" data-locale="{{ app.request.locale }}"></div>` but in that case the latter element would be replaced by your Vue template.

If that's the case you should put the data-attribute in an element over it and  instead of `this.$el.attributes['data-locale'].value` you write `this.$el.previousElementSibling.getAttribute('data-locale').value`

I would like to add also that your lifecycle hook is `beforeMount` but your element does not still exist at this point; try with `mounted()`instead